# How to create a totally separate instance of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to create an instant of an object in JavaScript which doesn't affect to any other instance of that object, here is an example:

```
var A = {
        b: "2", 
        c: "3", 
        d: {
            e: "5", 
            f:{
                    g: "7"
                },
            h: function(){
               return "8";
              }
            }
}
var a1 = Object.create(A);
var a2 = Object.create(A);
a1.d.f.g = 10;
console.log(a2.d.f.g);//Result is 10 while it was supposed to be 7
```

In the example above when `a1.d.f.g` is changed, `a2.d.f.g` is changed too. What's the matter?

I even tried `Object.assign({}, A)`, but the problem still remains.

```
var a1 = Object.assign({}, A);
var a2 = Object.assign({}, A);
```

**Update**:
Thanks to some answers which gave me the clue, after searching a lot I figured that there are two concepts related to object copy in JavaScript, `Shallow Copy` and `Deep Copy`, in shallow copy only top-level properties are copied but reference object properties in further levels will be shared, if you want to have a totally separate instance you need deep copy or deep clone.

> A shallow copy successfully copies primitive types like numbers and strings, but any object reference will not be recursively copied, but instead the new, copied object will reference the same object.
>
> If an object references other objects, when performing a shallow copy of the object, you copy the references to the external objects.
>
> When performing a deep copy, those external objects are copied as well, so the new, cloned object is completely independent from the old one.
>   [Source](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/)

Personally I think shallow and deep copy concepts in JavaScript seem weird, doesn't make sense, but it's what it is, plus, sort of [similar stuff](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/) exists in C# too. `Object.assign()` and `spread operator` make shallow copy so you'll need another function to make a deep clone for you.

Some people advise using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` but it doesn't work for properties that are function itself for example `a1.d.h()` in the sample above is not valid if you use JSON solution, moreover the type might change in some cases as it occurs for Date type for instance.

Some libraries are recommended but in my case I prefer not to use any third party. I figured out it's better to use a loop through reference object properties and create a deep clone, here is the method that I'm talking about:

```
function deepClone (obj) {
    var _out = new obj.constructor;

    var getType = function (n) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(n).slice(8, -1);
    }

    for (var _key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
            _out[_key] = getType(obj[_key]) === 'Object' || getType(obj[_key]) === 'Array' ? deepClone(obj[_key]) : obj[_key];
        }
    }
    return _out;
}
```

So it will become something like this eventually:

```
var a1 = deepClone(A);
var a2 = deepClone(A);
a1.d.f.g = 10;
console.log(a2.d.f.g);//Result is 7 now
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a deep clone, you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` to deep clone

```js
var A = {
        b: "2", 
        c: "3", 
        d: {
            e: "5", 
            f:{
                    g: "7"
                }
            }
}
var a1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));
var a2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));
a1.d.f.g = 10;
console.log(a2.d.f.g);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works, but would you tell me the reason? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mohammadlm71 these method creates a shallow copy of object not the deep clone, so the deep properties still reference to original object

Comment: Please note that this method won't copy functions.

Comment: I consider it as a sort of bug in JavaScript, anyway, I appropriate your guidance.

Comment: What should I do to copy functions too?

Comment: @Mohammadlm71 you can use [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep)